# Use of wildcards with readtext()

Tags: r, quanteda

A basic question. I have a bunch of transcripts (.docx files) I want to read into a corpus. I use readtext() to read in single files no problem.

```
dat <- readtext("~/ownCloud/NLP/interview_1.docx")
```

As soon as I put "*.docx" in my readtext statement it spits an error.

```
dat <- readtext("~/ownCloud/NLP/*.docx")

Error: '/var/folders/bl/61g7ngh55vs79cfhfhnstd4c0000gn/T//RtmpWD6KSx/readtext-aa71916b691c0cf3cabc73a2e04a45f7/word/document.xml' does not exist.
In addition: Warning message:
In utils::unzip(file, exdir = path) : error 1 in extracting from zip file
```

Why the reference to a zip file? I have only .docx files in the directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the same problem. The issue was there are some hidden/temp `.docx` files in that folder, if you delete them and then try the code it works.

To see the hidden files, go to the folder from where you are reading `docx` files and based on your OS select a way to show them. On my mac I used

```
CMD + SHIFT + .
```

Once you delete them, try the code again and it should work

```
library(readtext)
dat <- readtext("~/ownCloud/NLP/*.docx")
```

Comment: I could not see any hidden files in my Mac folder but copying the docx files to a new folder did the trick. Thanks.